# Automating XMPP server testing with multiple client instances

Tags: java, xmpp, functional-testing, smack

I'm working on a test suite for XMPP server. Currently I have implemented a client able to connect, create account, send stanzas taken from XML file, receive the reply, store it in another file and compare that with the expected output. I can create several clients, but I'm looking for concurrent operation.

How do I go about making multiple clients to communicate with each other? My vision - put the clients into separate threads and provide commands like 'wait for reply'.

Any advice is appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

All done on same thread in a single testcase.

- Create outgoing connection as user 1.
- Create incoming connection as user 2.
- Register PacketListener for your test stanza which writes to a BlockingQueue on incoming connection.
- Write stanza on outgoing connection.
- Call take() on the queue and test results.

Note: The PacketListener will get called on a separate thread spawned internally by Smack, which is why you need the BlockingQueue to coordinate the send and the reply.

Comment: +1 Also consider having several XMPPConnection instances each one with its own PacketListener and BlockingQueue to test message routing or multiuser chats.